# SDK having only device support

Tags: ios, sdk

I am currently working on a app in which I integrated a video SDK which has only device support but don't have simulator support, When I am trying to run on simulator it causes error, My question is that will apple accept the binary which support both simulator and device support or only device support is enough for upload my binary to store.

Comment: what the error.both simulator and device support or only device support is enough for upload my binary (Ans : anyone is fine)

Comment: Hi Anbu, ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 this is the error

Comment: it means `video SDK` does not support in simultor, it only works in device only

Comment: yes Anbu, it works perfect in device I have to know will apple accept these kind of app that support only device.

Comment: 100 % will accept, does not a problem, check my answer also I given the example and I used in one of my app , the app name is ZED, it is in live.

Comment: Sure I will check Anbu.

Answer (score 1):

Some Architeuture does not support the Simulator, for e.g if we use Epson printer , The printer SDK does not run in Simulator but perfectly its run in device why we go for some hardware functions, take core location its does not run in simulator for dynamic Fetch. so it does not a problem apple will approve your app if it does not cause any errors.